# audio tag cannot be parsed in html5 page

Tags: html

I link this JS page to an XML all element is views but the audio tag in xml file is not views in the html5 page ..any suggestion how to make this function retrieve the audio file and show it as html5 audi player.

```
init: function () {

    //jQuery ajax call to retrieve the XML file
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: XMLLIST.xml,
        dataType: "xml",            
        success: XMLLIST.parseXML
    }); 

}, // end: init()

parseXML: function (xml) {

    //Grab every single ITEM tags in the XML file
    var data = $('item', xml).get();
    //Allow user to toggle display randomly or vice versa
    var list = (XMLLIST.random) ? XMLLIST.randomize(data) : data;
    var i = 1;

    //Loop through all the ITEMs
    $(list).each(function () {

        //Parse data and embed it with HTML
        XMLLIST.insertHTML($(this));            

        //If it reached user predefined total of display item, stop the loop, job done.
        if (i == XMLLIST.display) return false;
        i++;
    });


}, // end: parseXML()

insertHTML: function (item) {

    //retrieve each of the data field from ITEM
    var url = item.find('url').text();
    var image = item.find('image').text();
    var audio=item.find('audio').text();
    var title = item.find('title').text();
    var desc = item.find('desc').text();
    var html;

    //Embed them into HTML code
    html = '<div class="item">';
    html += '<a href="' + url + '"><image"' + image + '" alt="' + title + '" />';

    html += '<span>' + title + '</span></a>';
    html += '<audio control="control"><span> ' +audio+' </span></audio>';
    html += '<p>' + desc + '</p>';
    html += '</div>';

    //Append it to user predefined element
    $(html).appendTo(XMLLIST.appendTo);

}, // end: insertHTML()


randomize: function(arr) {

    //randomize the data
    //Credit to JSFromHell http://jsfromhell.com/array/shuffle
    for(var j, x, i = arr.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x);
        return arr;

} // end: randomize()
```

}

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is used to iterate over a jQuery object, if you want to iterate over an array use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Here you have

```
$(list).each(function () {
```

which should be

```
$.each(list, function () {
```

since list is an array of dom nodes and not a jQuery object